# Caliburn micro autofac - Showing Results(log) in textbox WPF

Tags: autofac, caliburn.micro

I have a application that i am currently modifying to use caliburn micro.
The application has a log class that is bound to a textbox on a form. So all other classes automatically loggs their results to this textbox.

I cant figure out how i will convert this to caliburn micro.

Old code with Autofac

`builder.Register<ILogger>(h => new Logger(textBoxLog)).SingleInstance();`

Implementation:

```
public class Logger : ILogger
{
    public Logger(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox textBox)
    {
    }
 }
```

All sugesstions are wellcome.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this code smells. You do mix a service class and a control. Better do something like this. Define an event in your ILogger and its arguments type:
    public interface ILogger
    {
        event EventHandler NewUsageLogEntry;
    }

```
public class LogEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public LogEventArgs(string aMessage)
    {
        Message = aMessage;
    }

    public string Message { get; private set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class LogModeViewModel : ModeViewModel
{
    public LogModeViewModel(ILogger aLogger)
    {
        if (aLogger == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("aLogger", "Логгер не задан.");
        }

        Logger = aLogger;
        Logger.NewUsageLogEntry += OnNewUsageLogEntry;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ApplicationUsageLogEntry> LogMessages
    {
        get
        {
            if (mLogMessages == null)
            {
                mLogMessages = new ObservableCollection<ApplicationUsageLogEntry>();
            }

            return mLogMessages;
        }
    }

    private ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    private void OnNewUsageLogEntry(object aSender, LogEventArgs aEventArgs)
    {
        ApplicationUsageLogEntry lLogEntry = new ApplicationUsageLogEntry(aEventArgs.Message);
        LogMessages.Add(lLogEntry);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ApplicationUsageLogEntry> mLogMessages;
}

public class ApplicationUsageLogEntry
{
    public ApplicationUsageLogEntry(string aMessage)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aMessage))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("aMessage", "Сообщение не задано.");
        }

        Message = aMessage;
        HappenOn = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public string Message { get; private set; }

    public DateTime HappenOn { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string lResult = string.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss} | {1}", HappenOn, Message);
        return lResult;
    }
}
```

In my code I use a DataGrid to display log but you can easily modify LogMessages to be a string. After that you need to bind this property to your TextBox.Text.
A tip: update not your property directly. Update a private StringBuilder and after that assign result of StringBuilder.ToString() to your LogMessages string property.